# Spring Boot MongoDB find records by value in list

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have in my mongodb collection with news.

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("593a97cdb17cc6535522d16a"),
        "title" : "Title",
        "text" : "Test",
        "data" : "9.06.2017, 14:39:33",
        "author" : "Admin",
        "categoryList" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : null,
                "text" : "category1"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : null,
                "text" : "category2"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : null,
                "text" : "category3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Every news record has list of categories. I woudl like to find all news who has `category1` in `categoryList` I try do that by 
`newsRepository.findByCategoryList("category1");` but not working.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current repository method the generated query is

```
{ "categoryList" : "category1"}
```

What you need is

```
{ "categoryList.text" : "category1"}
```

You can create the query in two ways.

Using Repository

```
findByCategoryListText(String category)
```

Using Query Method

```
@Query("{'categoryList.text': ?0}")
findByCategoryList(String category)
```